# shp2pgsql command not working

Tags: postgresql, terminal, postgis

I am new to PostgreSQL and am trying to import a shapefile via the terminal with the following code:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4269 C:\MyData\roads\roads.shp roads | psql -U postgres -d <DBNAME>
```

The postgis extension has already been created.  But I continue to get a syntax error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists
postgres=# 
postgres=# shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 /Users/alexander/Downloads/pluto/pluto.shp pluto | psql -U postgres -d postgres;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "shp2pgsql"
LINE 1: shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 /Users/alexander/Downloads/pluto/pluto....
        ^
postgres=#
```

Any idea as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192908/1872)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's because [shp2pgsql](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg) is a command line executable. Something that you run in your shell (bash,sh etc). It's not intended to be executed in your psql console as you seem to be doing.